# Killer WiFi AX500-DG works unstable / does not work at all on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, 21.10

I have installed Ubuntu 21.10 on Dell XPS 15 9500. It works fine except for the WiFi module - Killer WiFi AX500-DG on. It is detected by the system but it has issues when trying to connect to the network. It refuses to connect to my network even though the password is correct and the same connection works perfectly on Windows 11. When trying to change networks it randomly fails to look for any new networks and the only option is to reboot the machine.  Linux is my primary working environment and the fact that wifi does not work is a huge issue for me.

Comment: Which kernel are you using?  ie. what do you get with `uname -r` & what do you get with `inxi -i`

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: you can search your hardware component and ubuntu version to make sure whether it's working for someone else or not on https://linux-hardware.org/.